# Using three points (x, y), How to find whether it is triangle or not

Tags: c++, math

I have an assignment in codeforces which says:
 
Like all problem solvers, Ebram loves eating crepe! As we all know, crepe usually served in a triangular shape. Now Ebram wants to know how large can a crepe side be! So he tries to draw a triangle on a plane using three points and calculate the maximum length of the three sides of the triangle. But sometimes he falls asleep as he has been busy with the team preparing the training problems! As a result, the three points he uses may not form a triangle that could represent a piece of crepe! A triangle can represent a piece of crepe only if it has a positive area. So you are here to help Ebram! Given the coordinates Ebram used, determine whether they form a triangle that could represent a piece of crepe or not.

 
 Input:
Three integer coordinates (X,Y) that represent the three points Ebram used. Each point on a separate line.

 
Output: If the points form a triangle that can represent a piece of crepe, print the square of the maximum length of the three sides of the triangle. Otherwise print "Poor boy" 
Examples

```
input 
1 1 
3 1 
3 9 
output 
68
```

```
input 
 -10 8 
  9 100 
  3 8 
  output 
  8825
```

```
input 
7 3 
3 3 
19 3 
output 
Poor boy
```

Here is my code that I used:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main () {
   double x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3;
    double area;
    double s1,s2,s3;
   double slope1, slope2;
cin >> x1 >> y1;
cin >> x2 >> y2;
cin >> x3 >> y3;
slope1 =((y2-y1)/(x2-x1));
slope2 =((y3-y2)/(x3-x2));
area = 0.5*abs(((x2-x1)*(y3-y1)-(x3-x1)*(y2-y1)));
if (slope1!=slope2 &&  (area)!=0){


    s1 = sqrt(((x1-x2)*(x1-x2))+((y1-y2)*(y1-y2)));
    s2 = sqrt(((x2-x3)*(x2-x3))+((y2-y3)*(y2-y3)));
    s3 = sqrt(((x1-x3)*(x1-x3))+((y1-y3)*(y1-y3)));
     if (s1 > s2 && s1 > s3)
        cout<<s1*s1<<endl;
     if (s2 > s1 && s2 > s3)
        cout<<s2*s2<<endl;
     if (s3 > s1 && s3 > s2)
        cout <<s3*s3<<endl;
}

else
    cout <<"Poor boy";
return 0;


}
```

First I find the slope1 and slope2 to check if the three points aren't at the same line. So If they're not equal it forms a triangle (crepe).
Using this:

```
slope1 =((y2-y1)/(x2-x1));
slope2 =((y3-y2)/(x3-x2));
```

Then I wrote a relation to find the area of triangle using this formula:

```
area = 0.5*abs(((x2-x1)*(y3-y1)-(x3-x1)*(y2-y1)));
```

Finally I put the if statements to find if it is a triangle or not and find the length of each side of the triangle then find the maximum length and print the square of it.

```
if (slope1!=slope2 &&  (area)!=0){


    s1 = sqrt(((x1-x2)*(x1-x2))+((y1-y2)*(y1-y2)));
    s2 = sqrt(((x2-x3)*(x2-x3))+((y2-y3)*(y2-y3)));
    s3 = sqrt(((x1-x3)*(x1-x3))+((y1-y3)*(y1-y3)));
     if (s1 > s2 && s1 > s3)
        cout<<s1*s1<<endl;
     if (s2 > s1 && s2 > s3)
        cout<<s2*s2<<endl;
     if (s3 > s1 && s3 > s2)
        cout <<s3*s3<<endl;
}

else
    cout <<"Poor boy";
return 0;


}
```

I tested the code in my compiler and it runs the i/o shown in the example perfectly fine. I submitted the code on codeforces but I stuck wrong answer at test 8 I don't know why?, and my code runs inputs and outputs fine. I will be very pleased if you help guys.

Comment: Assuming an infinite plane, unless all points lie on the same line they will form a triangle with positive area. So you just need to test if all points are on the same straight line to know if it's a valid triangle.

Comment: `slope1!=slope2` will be almost always true, even if the slopes are almost the same

Comment: I believe there's a reason for the description only mentioning positive area and not slopes.

Comment: The formula is (x1 - x2)/(y1-y2) - (x2 - x3)/(y2 - y3) != 0 then its a triangle

Comment: Well... You have a problem with `division by 0`. What if the coordinates are `(3, 4), (3, 5) and (5, 6)` (which is a valid triangle)? `((y2-y1)/(x2-x1))` will yield `(4 - 5)/(3-3)` which is `-1/0`. Likewise with `((y3-y2)/(x3-x2))`.

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen What should I do to avoid 1/0?

Comment: @AdamHussein: Check if the denominator is zero and if it is then the slope is undefined. I.e. It's a vertical line.

Comment: You have already computed the area (without division), you can check if it is 0, what else do you need? All the rest seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

As in Sani's answer, I recommend calculating the rise and run between each pair of points:

```
rise1 = y2 - y1
rise2 = y3 - y2
rise3 = y1 - y3

run1 = x2 - x1
run2 = x3 - x2
run3 = x1 - x3
```

Also the same, I recommend checking whether any two points are coincident. Note that this is equivalent to what Sani's code is checking:

```
if (rise1 = run1 = 0) or (rise2 = run2 = 0) or (rise3 = run3 = 0) then
    print "Poor Boy"
    return 0
```

Now, similar to Sani, we move on to checking whether the points are on a line. However, we can simplify the conditions to check somewhat. Note that, if no two points are on a vertical line, then the three points are on one line if the slopes between any two points are equal. That is, m1 = m2, m2 = m3, or m3 = m1, equivalently. We can check whether m1 = m2. This is true when rise1/run1 = rise2/run2, which is safe since we assume no points are on a vertical line. We can rearrange this to rise1 * run2 = rise2 * run1, again safely. If no two points are on a vertical line, this is the only check we need.

What if two points are on a vertical line? Then at least one of run1 and run2 will be zero. However, because we have already guaranteed no two points are coincident, we can be absolutely sure that if either of these is zero, the corresponding rise is non-zero. There are two other cases (besides no two points being on a vertical line):

- Exactly two points are on a vertical line. Then either run1 or run2, but not both, are zero. Without loss of generality, assume run1 is zero. Then the condition rise1 * run2 = rise2 * run1 simplifies to rise1 * run2 = 0. Because we know rise1 is not zero, this is satisfied only if run2 = 0, which contradicts our assumed case. This means that, in this case, the condition we derived earlier will produce the correct result and identify the points as not being on the same line.
- Three points are on a vertical line. Then both run1 and run2 are zero. Then the condition rise1 * run2 = rise2 * run1 simplifies to 0 = 0, which is always true. In this case, the condition will produce the correct result and identify three points as being on the same line.

Because the condition we derived for the case of no two points on a vertical line happens to produce the correct result for all other possible cases, we can use it in all cases (under the assumption no two points are coincident). Therefore, we don't need to check anything except rise1 * run2 = rise2 * run1:

```
if rise1 * run2 = rise2 * run1 then
    print "Poor Boy"
    return 0
```

Now we know we have a triangle and need to return the largest of the three sides. We need the sum of squared differences of respective coordinates. Luckily, we already have the coordinate differences, so:

```
d1 = (rise1 * rise1) + (run1 * run1)
d2 = (rise2 * rise2) + (run2 * run2)
d3 = (rise3 * rise3) + (run3 * run3)
return max(d1, d2, d3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your biggest problem is that you keep getting `division by 0` on inputs where the denominator is 0 when calculating the slope. I.e. Points `(3, 4), (3, 5) and (5, 6)` will yield `-1/0`.

Another thing is that you are "over-complicating" things.

This is a step by step example for clarity how to approach this (I.e. not optimal code):

```
// Check if any two points are the same. I.e. no triangle
if (x1 == x2 && y1 == y2 || x1 == x3 && y1 == y3 || x2 == x3 && y2 == y3) {
  cout << "Poor boy";
  return 0;
}

// Check if all points are on the same horizontal or vertical line
if (x1 == x2 && x1 == x3 || y1 == y2 && y1 == y3) {
  cout << "Poor boy";
  return 0;
}

// Calculate the nominators and denominators
nominator1 = y2-y1;
denominator1 = x2-x1;
nominator2 = y3-y2;
denominator2 = x3-x2;
nominator3 = y1-y3;
denominator3 = x1-x3;

// Calculate the slopes, if possible.
if (denominator1 == 0) slope1 = 0;
else slope1 = nominator1 / denominator1;
if (denominator2 == 0) slope2 = 0;
else slope2 = nominator2 / denominator2;
if (denominator3 == 0) slope3 = 0;
else slope3 = nominator3 / denominator3;

// Check if the three points form a triangle or a straight line.
// I.e. if all slopes are the same, it is a line.
if ((slope1 == slope2 && slope1 == slope3)) {
  cout << "Poor boy";
  return 0;
}

// Calculate the square of the length of each side
// (No abs is needed since a square of negative numbers is positive.)
// (Also no sqrt is needed since we're only interrested in the square of the longest side.)
side1 = (x2-x1)*(x2-x1) + (y2-y1)*(y2-y1);
side2 = (x3-x2)*(x3-x2) + (y3-y2)*(y3-y2);
side3 = (x1-x3)*(x1-x3) + (y1-y3)*(y1-y3);

// Note: This can be used instead which is the same calculation:
// side1 = denominator1 * denominator1 + nominator1 * nominator1;
// side2 = denominator2 * denominator2 + nominator2 * nominator2;
// side3 = denominator3 * denominator3 + nominator3 * nominator3;

// Get the longest side squared.
maxSide = side1 > side2 ? side1 > side3 ? side1 : side2 > side3 ? side2 : side3;

cout << maxSide;
```

*Disclaimer: Code not tested!*

Comment: I tried your code. when I entered (1, 1) , (3, 1) (3, 9) it didn't print "Poor boy" on the screen.

Comment: @AdamHussein: It shouldn't... Since that is a valid triangle... It should print `68`.

Comment: With your code it prints nothing.Can you edit it please? and I will approve your answer.

Comment: With the relation you used  of each side1, side2 and side3, If I enter (1, 1) , (3, 1) (3, 9) it will print 400 not 68

Comment: Fixed the `side2` and `side3` calculations. They were incorrect. It should print out 68 now. But as I said: Code is not tested. You should be able to get it working if there are any more calculation mistakes since every step is explained.

Comment: It also gives me wrong answer at test 9 in codeforces what else should I put in the if statements, this gonna blow my mind. (-10^9<=X,Y<=10^9)